# What is the logical/conceptual difference between .vagrant and .vagrant.d directory?

Tags: vagrant, devops, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I want to know logical/conceptual difference between .vagrant and .vagrant.d directory

And also, what is the difference between the following keys

(Please observe the path of these two) one of which is placed in .vagrant directory and the other one in .vagrant.d directory in Windows 7?

> C:\Users\username**.vagrant**\machines\default\virtualbox\private_key
>
> C:\Users\username**.vagrant.d**\insecure_private_key

Could not find anywhere in the documentation and on the Internet as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when does the private_key under .vagrant directory get created? I cant see it in my setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.vagrant.d` is usually placed in your home folder and stores system-wide data/settings, i.e. downloaded vagrant boxes.

`.vagrant` is placed in your environment/project folder and stores project-specific settings, i.e. current VM settings.
So if you work in `user/myproject`, create `Vagrantfile` there and exec `vagrant up`, then `user/myproject/.vagrant` directory will be created with VM specific data.

`.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` is default **insecure** private key to access your VMs, it's replaced by vagrant on first VM start with `private_key` from project's `.vagrant` directory. In your example: `private_key` for `default` VM started with `virtualbox` provider.

Comment: Great explanation! So, if I am configuring password less login using Putty, I should be able to connect to my VM if I directly convert the private key from .vagrant directory to .ppk format and then login without entering the password? (No use of insecure_private_key if it gets replaced as you mentioned)

Comment: Yes, you need to convert `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key` . You can notice key replacement during `vagrant up` process: _Inserting generated public key within guest..._ and _Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present..._.

Comment: Just checked and the above worked! Realized, as you mentioned, the insecure_private_key is just used once (at first start) and seems to be of no use post that. Thanks again!